# In Clojure how to apply function on a collection

Tags: xml, clojure, zipper

I am trying to apply function for extracting content of one tag from xml on a collection of tags. Basically, I am trying to  make a function that will extract content from xml, like this

```
(defn get-events
[xz] 
 (map (juxt 
    #(zf/xml1-> % :title zf/text) 
    #(zf/xml1-> % :performers :performer :name zf/text) 
    #(zf/xml1-> % :start_time zf/text) 
     #(zf/xml1-> % :stop_time zf/text))
 (zf/xml-> xz  :events :event)))
```

And my solution so far looks like this

```
(ns datamodel

(:use 
[net.cgrand.enlive-html :as en-html ])
(:require
[clojure.zip :as z] 
[clojure.xml :as xml ]
[clojure.data.zip.xml :as zf]
 [clojure.java.io :as io]
))


(def data-url "http://api.eventful.com/rest/events/search?   app_key=4H4Vff4PdrTGp3vV&keywords=music&location=Belgrade&date=Future")

(defn xz [url](z/xml-zip (xml/parse url)))

(defn xml-zipper [& tags](zf/xml-> (xz data-url) tags))

(defn func [& tags]#(zf/xml1-> (xml-zipper tags) % zf/text))

(def tags [:title :venue_name])
```

and in REPL when I try to apply func to tags like this

```
(map #((apply comp (reverse( func :events :event))) %) tags)
```

I get an empty collection ().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `def`ining `tags` you are not actually building a literal list but a call to `:title` with `:venue_name` as its argument. Try declaring `tags` as a list or a vector in the following way:

```
(def tags '(:title :venue_name)) ;list
(def tags [:title :venue_name]) ; vector
```

I suggest you clean up your code a little bit since there seems to be a number of problems with it:

1. Double requirement of `clojure.data.zip.xml`.
2. Extra parenthesis in the definition of the function `xz`.
3. `xz` is used as both an alias for a namespace and the name of a function.
4. Remove the enclosing parenthesis `func` anonymous function `(#(zf/xml1-> (xml-zipper tags) % zf/text))`, you are creating and calling that `fn` at the same time.

Hope it helps.

---

**EDIT**

I think I now get what you are trying to do. Here's a working version for the selector generator function: `selector`. Note that the argument `tag` can be either a single keyword or a sequence of keywords, in which case `apply` is used when calling `xml1->`.

```
(ns datamodel
  (:require [clojure.zip :as z] 
            [clojure.xml :as xml]
            [clojure.data.zip.xml :as zf]
            [clojure.java.io :as io]))

(def data-url "http://api.eventful.com/rest/events/search?app_key=4H4Vff4PdrTGp3vV&keywords=music&location=Belgrade&date=Future")

(defn parse [url]
  (z/xml-zip (xml/parse url)))

(defn selector [tag]
  (if (sequential? tag)
    #(apply zf/xml1-> % (concat tag [zf/text]))
    #(zf/xml1-> % tag zf/text)))

(defn get-events
  [xml & tags]
  (let [events (zf/xml-> xml :events :event)
        fs     (map selector tags)]
    (map (apply juxt fs) events)))

(-> data-url 
  parse 
  (get-events :title :start_time [:performers :performer :name] :stop_time)
  first 
  prn)
```

Comment: Thanks juan, but now I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong number of args (0) passed to: datamodel$func$fn :(

Comment: @Vesna I added item 4 in the problems list, which I think addresses the error you are seeing now.

Comment: I've changed it, still no luck, I'm wondering if it's possible to create list of functions